# What would cause a chest in my house to disappear?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Awhile back I bought the Hjerim house in Windhelm for the quest about the butcher guy. After I finished the quest I bought the armoury decoration from Jarleif and filled the racks and manikens with my stuff. The left over armour I put in one of the chests in the rooms upstairs (I can't remember which one) and didn't really go back in.  One of the things that I put in the chest was the dragon mask Nakriin.

Awhile later I found the wooden mask in the Labyrinthian and went back to get the mask to put on the bust but when I went to the bedroom all that was there was a chest. Before there was also a double bed and a wardrobe. I'm pretty sure I put it in the wardrobe but I'm not sure.  I checked every chest in the house trying to find it but now I can't. I think maybe it might be because I had my wife and two kids stay there for a while.

Can anybody tell me what could of happened?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the decoration status of the room got reset for some reason. One thing you can try is go back to the Jarl and see if you can buy the decoration for the room again. Given that there are quite some bugs in this game it is quite difficult to tell you what exactly happened to answer your question.

What I can recommend you only is to try to buy the decoration again. If that fails, it might be stuck in this status unless you start working with console commands to fix it. You can use the console commands also to get back your mask.